How to troubleshoot and fix API Request Authorization failed?
I'm finding $API Request Authorization failed errors in both my CiviCRM logs and my Drupal logs at two points where things are failing:

When I try to create recurring contributions (one-time contributions work fine, recurring contributions are stuck in Pending)
When I try to view a user dashboard at /civicrm/user (the user dashboard appears, but there are no entries - the first five sections just don't column headings with no data, then the Your Contacts section shows "None Found"; all entries appear just fine when I view a contact at /civicrm/contact/view)

The log entry looks something like this:
Location    https://dev.mysite.com/user/reset/1439448/1716522243/9STBEcjOf3BD8qNBta7Yw2aHHYIWSsKiZta4ge5GteA/login
Referrer    https://dev.mysite.com/user/reset/1439448
Message     $API Request Authorization failed = 
#0 /home/mysite/dev/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(151): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("API Request Authorization failed", TRUE) 
#1 /home/mysite/dev/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(256): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction)) 
#2 /home/mysite/dev/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/ext/civiimport/Civi/Api4/Event/Subscriber/ImportSubscriber.php(221): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute() 

(64 lines total)
I'm also getting an Ajax error when I try to view the /civicrm/user page:
Location    https://dev.mysite.com/civicrm/ajax/api4
Referrer    https://dev.mysite.com/civicrm/user
Message     AJAX Error ({error_id}): failed with exception Array ( [error_id] => 4RCG-vOye-FOSC [exception] => Civi\API\Exception\UnauthorizedException: "Authorization failed: CiviCRM APIv4 (Group::get)" 
#0 /home/mysite/dev/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(147): Civi\API\Kernel->authorize() 

(36 lines total)
How can I find out what's causing this and fix it?
I've got CiviCRM 5.73.1 and Drupal 10.2.6 .
Thank you!

Hi, Did you ever solve this?
I am also getting the same error but on a different task.
